# Avoid to insert path of SSH key pair when connecting through passwordless login

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I've set a passwordless connection through ssh using SSH key pair.
So if I run the command:

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/root_master master@ip
```

I'm able to connect to master@ip without typing the pwd.
However I would like to connect without typing

```
-i /root/.ssh/root_master
```

but just typing

```
ssh master@ip
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

localHost $ `ssh remotePassword@remoteHostname`

If you want to connect to remote server just by typing above command; you must create ssh trust between your local host and remote host.

**Step 1:** Create ssh setup on both the host. ( usually, .ssh directory is present at ~ directory )

**Step 2:** Generate RSA key pair on both the hosts. To generate RSA key pair

`cd ~; mkdir -p .ssh; cd .ssh`

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "id_rsa" -N "\" -P "\"; chmod 400 id_rsa`

`touch authorized_keys; touch known_hosts`

**Step 3:** Write `id_rsa.pub` file of local host to authorized_keys file of remote host and vice-versa (in case, you want to build both sides trust)

**Step 4:** Also make entry into known_hosts file or it will automatically create when you will connect for the first time.

This way you can create ssh trust between host and so make them passwordless.

Another way to do this is to usee `new ssh module` of perl.